# Django: Why is my "save_model()" not working?

Tags: django, forms, save, admin, verification

*I will be very, VERY grateful* if someone can help me figure out my coding problem. When I'm in the admin interface, no errors are generated.  However, nothing that I specify under my custom save_model(...) function seems to execute when I click "Save" for a Provider object under the admin interface.  I've condense my code down into little snap shots. ***What am I doing wrong?***

Side Note: This may sound strange, but I'm also trying to delete the object during the save process (it's supposed to overwrite to another "provider" object before doing so).

===================

## model.py

```
#models.py
...
class Provider(models.Model):  
  title = models.CharField(max_length=150)
  purpose = models.TextField()
  summary = models.TextField()
  email = models.EmailField()
  access_code = models.CharField(max_length=30, default=random_password)
  verified = models.BooleanField(default=False) #On/Off switch to display on database
  flagged = models.BooleanField(default=False) 
  revised = models.BooleanField(verbose_name = "New Update", default=False)
    # Will be True, if a revision has occured
        # On/Off switch state whether this is a revision of an existing Provider
    # This will be useful for creating a manager that lists updated providers
    # Note: Must delete Revised_Provider object after verification is complete
    # and UPDATE has occurred on save()

  #M2M Relations
  serviced_location = models.ManyToManyField(Location, through='ServicedLocations')
  services_offered = models.ManyToManyField(ServiceType, through='OfferedServices')
  insurances_accepted = models.ManyToManyField(InsuranceProvider, through='AcceptedInsurances')
  #contacts = models.ManyToManyField(Contact, blank=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.title

#Used for allow the provider to make change to their profile, and wait
#for verification before it will show up on regular search results
#Serves as a map for referencing a verified provider to a recent update (revision)
class Revision(models.Model): #Revised Providers (eg: Updated)
  provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider, null=True)
  date_revised = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=True)
  def __unicode__(self):
      return u'%s' % self.provider

class ServicedLocations(models.Model):
  location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
  provider = models.ForeignKey(Provider) #Pre-Verified or Verified Settings
  revision = models.ForeignKey(Revision, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
...etc...
```

===================

## admin.py

```
#admin.py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.forms.models import ModelForm
from django import forms
from health.providers.models import *
class ProviderAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = self.cleaned_data
        flagged = cleaned_data.get("flagged")
        verified = cleaned_data.get("verified")

        if flagged == True and verified == True:
        raise forms.ValidationError("You cannot verify a 'flagged' provider. If you meant to verify this provider, be sure to uncheck 'flagged'")
               # Just in case someone accidently verified a flagged provider       
        return cleaned_data

class ProviderAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):    
    list_per_page = 100
    list_display = ('date_added', 'title', 'state', 'verified', 'flagged')
    list_display_links = ('title',)
    list_filter = ('verified', 'flagged', 'revised')
    search_fields = ['title',]
    filter_horizontal = ('services_offered',)
    form = ProviderAdminForm

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        ProviderID = obj.id
        try: #see if a revision exists in the table
            Compare = Revision.objects.get(id=ProviderID)

            OldProviderID = Compare.provider.id
            OldProvider = Provider.objects.get(id=OldProviderID)

            RevisedProvider = Provider.objects.get(id=ProviderID) 
            RevisedProviderID = RevisedProvider.id

            if change:  #Check to see if we changed anything important
                verified = form.cleaned_data['verified']
                #Means we would have had to manually verified it

                if verified == True: 
                #This means that we have approved to update the old Provider
                #After copying the data over, we destroy what we are saving

                    obj.revised = False
                    obj.save()
                    #If we verfied it, revised = False  

                    OldProvider = RevisedProvider #Update Existing Provider Table
                    OldProvider.save()


                    NewLocations = ServicedLocations.objects.get(provider=RevisedProviderID)
                    OldLocations = ServicedLocations.objects.get(provider=OldProviderID)
                    OldLocations = NewLocations
                    OldLocations.save()
                    NewLocations.delete()


                    Compare.delete() #Delete from database
                    RevisedProvider.delete() #Delete Final Copy of Table

                    return HttpResponseRedirect("admin/providers/provider/%s/" % OldProviderID) #Redirect them to updated provider

        except Revision.DoesNotExist:
         print "This provider does not have any unverified revisions"

        return super(ProviderAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)       

admin.site.register(Provider, ProviderAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where does the code poop out? Are you saying it won't execute **at all**? not even log statements on the first line? or are you saying your expected changes are not being made in the DB?

I've tried recreating your situation with various theories but can't reproduce a problem. Can you describe in more detail what the problem is? Try doing some pdb.set_trace(), dig around and give us some more details : )

Since you haven't provided an exception, you need to provide more information about what's wrong.

PS: I'm reading through your code but it's very hard to read! Classes look like instances which look like variables... Just a heads up it goes against coding conventions for Python as you can see with the syntax highlighter thinking your CapitalizedObjects are classes.

---

It looks like you are saving the main object, changing its referenced name a few times and then saving it again, then deleting it! Very confusing stuff going on here...

Here's what I see...

RevisedProvider is the same instance as obj.
 `RevisedProvider = Provider.objects.get(id=obj.id)`

Then, you assign RevisedProvider to OldProvider, and call `save()` on that, which is the same instance as obj (2 saves).

At the end, you delete `RevisedProvider.delete()`, which is the object you are editing.

When I try to reproduce that code, and delete the instance I'm editing,  django throws a ValidationError.

Sooo, we need more information to help. Where are the other oddities?

Comment: Thanks :-)  please see my comment above

Answer (score 0):

Yuji,

Thank-you for your tips, and I appreciate your hard work at looking into my disorganized coding.

Originally my goal was to have a list of Providers that had to be verified (in the admin interface) before appearing in the public search results.  The problem I encountered was that if a Provider updated their own contact information, we automatically set verified=False (in case something inappropriate was posted). So, a Provider who updated their information would then have to be reverified before appearing at all on the database.  This was awful, because they would instantly be removed from the search results.  That's why I introduced revisions to my database, so that a provider could edit and update their information at anytime.  Now the *new* changes just wouldn't appear until we manually verified updated version of the Provider's information.

I wanted to keep the ID of the contact the same, so that logging history would remain the same.  This became too complicated.  So, just ended up making it so that it'd delete the old version upon a save() if *verified* was checked as True.

### admin.py

```
def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
    providerid = obj.id
    if Revision.objects.filter(revised_provider=providerid).exists() and obj.revised == True:
        compare = Revision.objects.get(revised_provider=providerid)

        oldproviderid = compare.provider.id
        oldprovider = Provider.objects.get(id=oldproviderid)

        revisedproviderid = compare.revised_provider.id
        revisedprovider = Provider.objects.get(id=revisedproviderid) 


        if change:  #Check to see if we changed anything important
            verified = form.cleaned_data['verified']
            #Means we would have had to manually verified it

            if verified == True: 
            #This means that we have approved to update the old Provider
            #After copying the data over, we destroy what we are saving
                obj.revised = False
                obj.save()
                #If we verfied it, revised = False  

                compare.delete() #Delete Revision 
                oldprovider.delete() #Delete Old Provider

    return super(ProviderAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
```